# Laravel App not always showing my changes in real time.. caching?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and having a weird problem whereby sometimes if I make a change in my JS files, the change doesn't apply.

I can see the `GET` request to the file through the console however it still contains old content. I can even remove everything inside of the file and the application still shows old content. It's only when I delete the file that it recognizes that something is wrong.

Is there some sort of caching going on that I need to know about?
I am using `Laravel 5.1` however at this point, Laravel is really only handling the routing at this point.

Eventually, the changes come through. Am I going crazy or is this one of the gotcha's I should know about with `AngulasJS`?

Comment: This issue could be coming from your server. If your web server is nginx ensure static files are not being cached

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$scope.$apply()
```

The way angularjs works is when one of the binded fields (ng-model) is changed in the browser, angularjs updateds the data model in the scope (controller or directive).

If you have code with callbacks when the new data is to be assigned to the data model, you'll need to run $scope.$apply().  This statement tells anguarljs to rebind the data model to the view (html).

Depends on where you have the $apply statement, you might want to test for $scope.$$phase because if the digest/apply is already in process and you run $apply, you'll get a Javascript run time error.